# Is there an uncertainty relation for fields, and if yes, what does it mean?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In quantum mechanics, we have the famous uncertainty relation
$$\Delta x \Delta p\geq  \frac{\hbar}{2}$$
which is a [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation#Uncertainty_relation_and_commutators) of the canonical commutation relation $[x,p] = i \hbar$.

*Is there are similar relation in quantum field theory?* In particular, is there are relation of the form
$$\Delta \phi \Delta \Pi \neq 0 ,$$
where $\Pi$ denotes the conjugate momentum? This seems likely since the canonical commutation relation in QFT reads $[\phi(t,x),\Pi(t,y)] = i \hbar \delta (x-y)$. Moreover, if such a relation exists, how is it commonly interpreted?

Comment: You might consider the [EM field](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node464.html).

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32789/uncertainty-of-fields-with-many-harmonic-modes) and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191042/uncertainty-principle-in-quantum-field-theory). Read up on Heitler's "The quantum theory of radiation",  Ch II sec 8. It is a long and glorious story, started by Jordan and Pauli in 1928, and crucially applied by Bohr and Rosenfeld to prove the inevitability of quantization of fields.

Answer (score 0):

QFT is sometimes introduced as a collection of oscillatory modes "in a box", each being a harmonic oscillator. With a finite number of modes (corresponding to a momentum cut-off) this is just a multidimensional harmonic oscillator so there is an uncertainty relation like we have in 3-space. This idea can be extended to infinite dimensions using some higher math.